# LightMap not working properly

Tags: textures, uv-mapping, lightmap

I've made a chips bag model for my game:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Eae.jpg

And I textured it like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmEUO.jpg

and I googled on how to make lightmaps all of them say "Smart UV project" but when I do that, texture on my model gets broken, so thats why I dont want to use smart uv project

Is there another way?, it has to be.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a lightmap in your 3D-modeling-program (e.g. blender).
2. Load it into your game without changing the object's UV-coordinates
3. Make your game multiply the [diffuse-texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Eae.jpg) with the lightmap.